# Parsing raw video without caps in gstreamer

Tags: bash, video, video-streaming, gstreamer, shared-memory

I have the following pipelines

sender

```sh
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! "video/x-raw,width=1280, height=720,framerate=30/1" ! shmsink socket-path=/tmp/stream sync=true wait-for-connection=false shm-size=100000000
```

receiver

```sh
gst-launch-1.0 shmsrc socket-path=/tmp/stream is-live=1 ! video/x-raw,width=1280,height=720,framerate=30/1,format=BGR ! videoconvert ! queue ! autovideosink
```

Is there a way i can include the caps data in the shared memory instead of specifying that data on the receiver side?

what i want is something like

```sh
gst-launch-1.0 shmsrc socket-path=/tmp/stream is-live=1 ! video/x-raw ! videoconvert ! queue ! autovideosink
```

This currently shows

```sh
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter0: Filter caps do not completely specify the output format
```

I can modify the sender as much as possible but want to keep the receiver more general to my needs.

The above is possible with encoded video like h264 but not raw video.